# Is there a way to simplify redundant conditionals?

Tags: logic, compilers

For example if I've this:

```
if a == false then return true else
if a == true and b == false return true else
if a == true and b == true then return false
```

can be simplified to

```
if a == false || b == false then return true
return false;
```

Truth Table would look like this:

```
F T = T
F F = T
T F = T
T T = F
```

I want to come up with a solution that can get arbitrarily big conditional but condense it to the  minimum state and get rid of cases which will never occur.

I'd imagine one way would be to generate a truth table and work your way up from there, another would be to find and combine combos with similar out comes and come up with a pattern that would keep the existing truth table intact.

Comment: The best solution will probably depend heavily on the details: I don't think there will be a single technique that will be best in all situations.  For instance, I think it will depend on how many variables you have, as well as on the specific computer architecture you're working on.

Comment: There are algorithms, like [Quine-McCluskey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm). See [Quine's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2308219?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) and [McCluskey's paper](https://archive.org/details/bstj35-6-1417).